# Gcloud and docker confusion

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I am very lost on the steps with gcloud verse docker.  I have some gradle code that built a docker image and I see it in images like so

```
(base) Deans-MacBook-Pro:stockstuff-all dean$ docker images
REPOSITORY                         TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
gcr.io/prod-stock-bot/stockstuff   latest    b041e2925ee5   27 minutes ago   254MB
```

I am unclear if I need to run docker push or not or if I can go strait to gcloud run deploy so I try a docker push like so

```
(base) Deans-MacBook-Pro:stockstuff-all dean$ docker push gcr.io/prod-stockstuff-bot/stockstuff
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/prod-stockstuff-bot/stockstuff]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: gcr.io/prod-stockstuff-bot/stockstuff
```

I have no idea why it says the image doesn't exist locally when I keep listing the image.  I move on to just trying gcloud run deploy like so

```
(base) Deans-MacBook-Pro:stockstuff-all dean$ gcloud run deploy stockstuff --project prod-stock-bot --region us-west1 --image gcr.io/prod-stockstuff-bot/stockstuff --platform managed
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [stockstuff] in project [prod-stock-bot] region [us-west1]
X Deploying... Image 'gcr.io/prod-stockstuff-bot/stockstuff' not found.
  X Creating Revision... Image 'gcr.io/prod-stockstuff-bot/stockstuff' not found.
  . Routing traffic...
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Image 'gcr.io/prod-stockstuff-bot/stockstuff' not found.
```

I am doing this all as a playground project and can't seem to even get a cloud run deploy up and running.

I tried [the spring example](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/java) but that didn't even create a docker image and it failed anyways with

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Missing required argument [--image]: Requires a container image to deploy (e.g. `gcr.io/cloudrun/hello:latest`) if no build source is provided.
```

Comment: Do you see the container on the GCR console? https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/ It might be that you just named a container like that URL, and was never pushed to the GCR repository.

Comment: I really recommend you don't use the `latest` tag, btw. It *will* bite you on the arse one day

Comment: Hi @Dean Hiller i don't see this image   " gcr.io/prod-stockstuff-bot/stockstuff " when you list images in local system. Tag the image with this name " gcr.io/prod-stock-bot/stockstuff " and re run the gcloud run command.

Comment: thankyou @Sri you nailed it.  I kept missing I had a typo!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when an image is not tagged locally/correctly. Steps you can try on your side.

- Create image locally with name **stockstuff** (do not prefix it with gcr and project name while creating).
- Tag image with gcr repo detail

```
$ docker tag stockstuff:latest gcr.io/prod-stockstuff-bot/stockstuff:latest
```

- Check if your image is available in GCR (must see your image here, before deploying on cloudrun).

```
$ gcloud container images list --repository gcr.io/prod-stockstuff-bot
```

- If you can see your image in list, next you can try to deploy gcloud run with below command (as yours).

```
gcloud run deploy stockstuff --project prod-stock-bot --region us-west1 --image gcr.io/prod-stockstuff-bot/stockstuff --platform managed
```

Comment: The issue was a darn typo that took forever to figure out gcr.io/prod-stock-bot/stockstuff vs. gcr.io/prod-stockstuff-bot/stockstuff - fun with typos

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 contexts that you need to be aware.

1. Your local station, with your own docker.
2. The cloud based Google Container Registry: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/
3. Cloud Run product from GCP

So the steps would be:

1. Build your container either locally or using Cloud Build
2. Push the container to the GCR registry,
   if you built locally

   docker tag busybox gcr.io/my-project/busybox
   docker push gcr.io/my-project/busybox
3. Deploy to Cloud Run a container from Google Cloud Repository.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this image `gcr.io/prod-stockstuff-bot/stockstuff` when you list images in the local system. You can create a new image by tagging that image with this image `gcr.io/prod-stock-bot/stockstuff` and re-run the gcloud run command.

Answer (score 1):

for the context I am using Flask (python)

I solved this by

1. update `gcloud-sdk` to the latest version

```
gcloud components update
```

2. add `.dockerignore`, I'm guessing because of the python cache

```
Dockerfile
README.md
*.pyc
*.pyo
*.pyd
__pycache__
.pytest_cache
```

3. expose the port to env $PORT

```
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:app
```